# Disable Scrolling for touch input

Tags: windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, modern-ui

I have this xaml in my page:

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                        <TextBlock Name="Content" IsTextSelectionEnabled="True" 
                            FontSize="20"
                            TextWrapping="Wrap"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                    </ScrollViewer>
```

There is no option to horizontally scroll with the mouse. However, if I use touch mode (I use the simulator) I can drag the text from left to right with my 'finger'.

If I comment out the ScrollViewer this behaviour stops. I can only assume that `Disabled` `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` is not preventing the touch user from scrolling horizontally. This is a minor annoyance, but how can I prevent this horizontal scrolling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll also want to disable [`HorizontalScrollMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer.horizontalscrollmode.aspx). `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` is a separate property from the one that handles the actual behavior, which I get is a bit strange because 95% of the times you either `Disable` both or set both to `Auto`, bit I guess it is just an API design choice that gives you a bit more power.